# setWebViewClient on public static class

Tags: android

Lesson1.java

```
 public static class LessonListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    String justifyTag = "<html><body style='text-align:justify;LINE-HEIGHT:20px;font-size:12px;padding-top:0px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;'>%s</body></html>";
    String justifyTag1 = "<html><body style='text-align:justify;font-weight:bold;color:white;background:#2E8B57;text-align:center;LINE-HEIGHT:20px;font-size:12px;padding-top:0px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;'>%s</body></html>";
    View mView;


    public LessonListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setData_one(String data_one){

        //TextView post_lesson1 = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_lesson1);
        //post_lesson1.setText(data_one);


        WebView post_lesson1 = (WebView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_lesson1);
        String dataString = String.format(Locale.US, justifyTag1, data_one);
        post_lesson1.loadDataWithBaseURL("", dataString, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
        post_lesson1.setWebViewClient(new Lesson1Hlink(this));

    }
```

Lesson1Hlink.java

```
public class Lesson1Hlink extends WebViewClient {

private Context context;

public Lesson1Hlink(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}




@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.equals("hrupin://second_activity")){
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Simulation7.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
}
```

}

I am still a newbie in android programming. I can't seem to figure out why am I not be able to call the Lesson1Hlink in the post_lesson1.setWebViewClient(new Lesson1Hlink(this));

it says that "Lesson1Hlink (android.content.Context) in Lesson1Hlink cannot be applied to (com.example........LessonListViewHolder)". Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks and best wishes

Comment: Try getting this example working outside of a Recyclerview https://github.com/ihrupin/samples/tree/master/android/Send_Intent_By_Hyperlink_Click/src/com/hrupin/sample/webviewintent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `Lesson1Hlink` constructor requires a `Context` param and `this` (in `new Lesson1Hlink(this)`) is presented as `LessonListViewHolder` not a `Context`. So you can change it to this:

```
post_lesson1.setWebViewClient(new Lesson1Hlink(mView.getContext()));
```

Maybe, `Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag` so, try change your code to start `activity` like below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Simulation7.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
return true;
```

Comment: Your code works, but I wonder why it won't open my Simulation7.class.

It only displays "Web page not available"

-By the way im using firebase database

Comment: @Ryo Obviously you're not loading `hrupin://second_activity`

Comment: @criket_007 I am loading it (retrieving the link on my firebase database)

Comment: @NamNH It works like a charm!!!! I'm so idiot, it shoud be post_lesson3.setWebViewClient(new Lesson1Hlink(mView.getContext()));

because i'am calling the link "hrupin:\\second_activity" in my data_three

Thank you very much :))

Comment: @Ryo Glad to hear that !